# Add two components/objects into each panels of tableLayoutPanel programatically - C#

Tags: c#, object, components, panel, tablelayoutpanel

I have a `tableLayoutPanel` (size of 10x10 columns & rows added from the toolbox) and I have added single `Panel` into every cells so I could add two objects/components into a cell. Every cell contains a `label` and a `button`. The problem is I couldn't add the two components into a `panel` programatically. What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
private int[,] grid;
private Button[,] btn_grid;
private Label[,] lbl_grid;
private int timer = 0;
private Panel[,] pnl_grid;

        private bool createGrid()
        {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            grid = new int[width, height];
            pnl_grid = new Panel[width, height];
            btn_grid = new Button[width, height];
            lbl_grid = new Label[width, height];

            for (int x = 0; x <width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    btn_grid[x, y] = createButton(x, y);
                    lbl_grid[x, y] = createLables(x,y);
                    pnl_grid[x, y] = createPanels(x, y);

                    **//something's missing here to add the 2 components into a panel** 

                    tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(pnl_grid[x,y]);


                }
            }}


private Button createButton(int gridX, int gridY)
{
    Button bttn = new Button();
    bttn.Text = "";
    bttn.Name = gridX.ToString() + " " + gridY.ToString();
    bttn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
    Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { bttn, });
    bttn.Click += new System.EventHandler(bttnOnclick);
    //bttn.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.bttnOnRightClick);

    return bttn;
}

private Label createLables(int gridX, int gridY)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Name = gridX.ToString() + " " + gridY.ToString();
    lbl.Text = "0";
    lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
    //lbl.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75f, lbl.Font.Style, lbl.Font.Unit);
    Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { lbl, });
    return lbl;
}

private Panel createPanels(int gridX, int gridY)
{
    Panel pnl = new Panel();
    pnl.Name = gridX.ToString() + " " + gridY.ToString();
    //pnl.Text = "0";
    pnl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
    //lbl.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75f, lbl.Font.Style, lbl.Font.Unit);
    Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { pnl, });
    return pnl;
}
```

Thank you for your appreciated attention and help!

Comment: actually what are you atrying to do, your code seems to add labels and buttons in Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `Controls.AddRange` call from `createLables, createButton createPanels` method.
Then you can modify your createpanels method as below

```
private Panel createPanels(int gridX, int gridY)
{
    Label lbl = lbl_grid[gridX,gridY];
    Button btn = btn_grid[gridX,gridY];
    Panel pnl = new Panel();
    pnl.Name = gridX.ToString() + " " + gridY.ToString();
    //pnl.Text = "0";
    pnl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
    //lbl.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75f, lbl.Font.Style, lbl.Font.Unit);
    pnl.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { lbl,btn });
    lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    btn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    return pnl;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I haven't said anything (before the award) because you were the one commenting firstly (although your comment wasn't in the right direction precisely) but, actually, your answer is a copy of mine; and well...

Comment: @varocarbas i dont need to copy an answer, when i was typing answer there was no answers, when i finished posting my answer I saw your answer. this doesn't mean copy. everybody knows 1+1 =2, since you told 1+1=2 it doesnt mean that whoever saying the same answer is copying. so pls update ur comment in right direction

Comment: Ok, OK... everything clear. I only wanted to make sure. Because honestly I found pretty surprising seeing an answer basically saying the same than mine 2 minutes later. But I do understand that when you are typing you don't realise about what has been written by others. I take your word.

Comment: @varocarbas yes excatly. we are here to help others why we want to steal someone else code and to get upvotes? it doesn't make any sense. cheers lets keep helping.

Comment: Sure, that's why I found this a bit weird (never happened before to me). But don't take it badly: I like saying things openly when I have a doubt, don't think that I am insinuating anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33419/discussion-between-sriram-sakthivel-and-varocarbas)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine until the last moment when you have to add the controls to the `tableLayourPanel` or to the `panel`. You just add the `panel` but not the `button`/`label` to the `panel`.

Thus, you have to options:

Adding `button` and `label` to the `panel` and the `panel` to the `tableLayoutPanel` (which seems the most logical one):

```
btn_grid[x, y] = createButton(x, y);
lbl_grid[x, y] = createLables(x,y);
pnl_grid[x, y] = createPanels(x, y);
pnl_grid[x, y].Controls.Add(btn_grid[x, y]);
pnl_grid[x, y].Controls.Add(lbl_grid[x, y]);
tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(pnl_grid[x,y]);
```

or adding the three elements directly to the `tableLayoutPanel`:

```
btn_grid[x, y] = createButton(x, y);
lbl_grid[x, y] = createLables(x,y);
pnl_grid[x, y] = createPanels(x, y);
tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(btn_grid[x,y]);
tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(lbl_grid[x,y]);
tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(pnl_grid[x,y]);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and help however I have tried your given code (1st code), it shows none of errors but after compiling, each panel doesn't have the two objects (a label behind a button) and I don't know why because the code seems right while the 2nd code looks like we just add 1 component into each cell of tableLayoutPanel

Comment: My code and the one from Sriram Sakthivel do basically the same and thus should deliver the same output (= the elements are included in the panel). Bear in mind that he has performed some changes in the panel which affect the final appearance of what you see. But with both approaches, buttons and labels are in the correponding panels.

Comment: Could you help me to give the design code (not from the function like Sriram Sakthivel gave) so the button will be positioned on top of the label?

Comment: When you add a control it is located in a random position (or, at least, unkown to you). You have to position them properly. Bear in mind that once the button and the label are added to the panel, the reference point is given by it (by the panel), that is, 0,0 (for button and label) is located in the left/bottom corner of the panel. Thus, the first thing you have to do after adding the objects is relocating them.